# Pagination strategy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to add paging to my Views. I looked into the PagedList (Nuget package) and it's really nice. The problem I have with it, is that it needs to pull in all the records from the database. As you can see, it would not be very efficient if there are millions of rows.

Are there any Nuget Paging packages that don't require you to pull in all the database records?
Will I have to write my own custom paging?

Comment: I'm not aware of any nuget packages but to be fair I don't play around or research much in them. what I can say is that it is not difficult to create your pagination in SQL Server statements. So really, as you discovered, it is best to page at the data source level, not afterwards. to be honest, I don't know why those developers who pull everything then page get away with it - they need a slap across the wrist IMHO!

Comment: If you use `IQueryable` with `PagedList` it won't pull all of the records.

Comment: Just my opinion but I wouldn't waste time on sophisticated paging when dealing with millions of rows. I'd go for smart filtering and/or search optimization. Let's be honest: How many times does anybody page beyond the 3rd page in a Google search result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick search for the `PagedList` github, I actually came across this quote from the author which specifically answers your question:

> Hi, I'm the creator of the PagedList library. If you are using PagedList with an IQueryable (via Entity Framework, Linq2Sql, NHibernate.Linq, etc) the library will definitely not load the whole list in order to get another page.
>
> If, for some reason, you cannot use IQueryable there is a StaticPagedList class that will allow you to generate your own IPagedList instance without iterating over the entire collection:
>
> https://github.com/troygoode/pagedlist#example-2-manual-paging

Taken from: http://forums.asp.net/t/1819810.aspx

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences, I've always created my own custom paging. It has always worked out better (in terms of flexibility) to just create my own. There is a plug in out there that may help you if you don't want to go that route. I have not used it, but I have looked at the example and it may be something that can work for you.

[Ajax Paging With Bootstrap In MVC 4](http://mvcpaging.apphb.com/)

I would recommend downloading the example project they provide, should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I have too much invested in PagedList to switch.